# pgdb.connect() causes segmentation error in python 2.7.3

Tags: python, postgresql-9.2

I just compiled and installed an instance of postgres 9.2.1. And python 2.7.3. On OpenSuSE 12.2, running on a xeon server. I then downloaded pygresql and tried to connect to database using pgdb but this crashes python. Here is the trace:

```
Retrieving package PyGreSQL-4.0-200.1.2.x86_64                       (1/1),  85.0 KiB (402.1 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: PyGreSQL-4.0-200.1.2.x86_64.rpm ........................................................[done]
Installing: PyGreSQL-4.0-200.1.2 ...................................................................[done]

rikki:~/Downloads # python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 14 2012, 08:58:41) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pgdb
>>> c=pgdb.connect()
Segmentation fault
```

Using anything but "" or localhost or  works "OK".

```
rikki:~/Downloads # python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 14 2012, 08:58:41) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pgdb
>>> d=pgdb.connect(host="localhost")
Segmentation fault

rikki:~/Downloads # python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 14 2012, 08:58:41) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pgdb
>>> d=pgdb.connect(host="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb.py", line 482, in connect
    dbtty, dbuser, dbpasswd)
pg.InternalError: could not translate host name "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" to address: Name or service not known

>>>
```

The database is accessible:
    rikki:~/Downloads # psql -U cw
    psql (9.2.2)
    Type "help" for help.

```
cw=# select now();  
             now              
------------------------------
 2013-05-14 09:08:49.54825-07
(1 row)

cw=#
```

At the same time I have a desktop with a similar installation that works fine.

What should I be checking for in my installation?

Thanks.

--EDIT-- Trying with `psycopg2-2.5-py2.7` gives same kinds of error:

```
>>> con=psycopg2.connect(host="z",db="cw",user="cw")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: invalid connection option "db"


    >>> con=psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="cw",user="cw")
    Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Would you mind trying the same with `psycopg2`? (I'm curious whether it's the database driver or the Python module that's getting the error)

Comment: @Nisan: please see my edits. Same errors.

Comment: sounds like the error isn't in Python, but in one of the binaries it (or both modules) are using to connect with Postgres.

Comment: My next guess would be: either the dependencies for pgdb/psycopg2 are broken (or not installed by whatever installed them), or the postgresql instance itself could be broken/incomplete. I haven't ever run this on Suse, so I can't really offer any better tech advice on this.

Comment: Thanks Nisan. psql works predictably on -h param. So my guess would be on the dependencies. I installed postgres from source, and python, pgdb, psycopg2 using zypper (binaries).

Comment: It looks like both modules use `libpq-fe` and `libpq-fs`. Have you tried reinstalling `libpq5` and `libpq-dev` (these are the ubuntu/debian names, so they may be under a differently named package for OpenSuse)?